# Multiprocessing Pool Map / Starmap Initiation before async execution?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, environment-variables, pool

I can execute `launch_training_job` function `len(experiments)` times with 4 processes using

```
p = Pool(4)
p.starmap(launch_training_job, experiments)
```

But I want to execute accordingly based on which process is executing it

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = 0
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = 1
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = 2
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = 3
```

before the processes start executing the function. I couldn't really find examples or documentation on how to prepend initialization routine before the function is called.

**How do I do this?**

Comment: You can pass an `initializer` method to the Pool, which will run for each process, maybe this can help you? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

Comment: Are you looking to bind each of your Pool workers to a certain CUDA device?  Depending on what you want to do there's `p.apply_async(...)` in addition to Ron's answer.